# Vertical alignment of `tabular` while using the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` option

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to list a paper on an academic CV with the following code

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{p{.8\textwidth} @{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small{A very long paper title with author names and other bibliographic information that spills over onto the next line.} & 
      \begin{tabular}{r} 
      2024 \\ \small{Expected}
      \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular*}
```

It almost works, but the lines of "A very long..." and "2024" are not vertically aligned.

[image]

How can I fix this? I've been playing around with different ideas, such as using `\makecell{Some really \\ longer text}` for the second column, but the same problem appears. Some sources say using `[t]` in `tabular` should align the text at the top, but this just breaks when I try it.

Comment: `\small{A...` note `\small` does not take an argument, just use `\small A...`

Answer (score 3):

(updated this answer after the OP provided further information regarding the desired layout)

I would counsel *against* frequent font size changes. Instead, I'd like to suggest that you switch to using a two-column `tabularx` environment, set its target width to `\textwidth`, employ `\RaggedRight` (aka flushleft) in the first column (and set its usable width to `0.8\textwidth`) and `\RaggedLeft` (aka flushright) in the second column; its width is calculated LaTeX as a residual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' and '\RaggedLeft' macros
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
   >{\RaggedRight\small}p{0.8\textwidth} 
   >{\RaggedLeft\small}X @{}}
A very long paper title with author names and other bibliographic information that spills over onto the next line. & 
2024\newline Expected \\ % <-- use '\newline' to force a line break *within* an X-type column
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This gives the correct alignment, but how can I keep the `.8 \textwidth` for the first column of text?

Answer (score 3):

Why `0.97\textwidth`? Anyway, use a `t`op aligned tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.8\textwidth}r@{}}
  \small
  A very long paper title with author names and other bibliographic
  information that spills over onto the next line. &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  2024 \\ \small Expected
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

With better syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\NewDocumentCommand{\paper}{mmO{}}{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.8\textwidth}r@{}}
  \small #1 & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}} #2 \\ \small #3 \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular*}\par
}


\begin{document}

\paper{A very long paper title with author names and other bibliographic
  information that spills over onto the next line.}{2024}[Expected]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `showframe` just to show the placement with respect to the margins. The lines will disappear as soon as you remove the package for the production version.

Comment: As for the `.97\textwidth`, I was going off of [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/charless-cv-template/mnhkbhwyytfv) CV template. I think the idea was to give a little padding so that the section lines extend a bit past the text.

Answer (score 1):

- If I correctly understand you, you not need the of  `multirow` package. Just write text in the second column it two lines (by help of `makecell` package and change  align of the `X` column type from `p` to `m`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\bigskip
    \begin{table}[!htb]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
%\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X l @{}}
A very long paper title with author names and other bibliographic information that spills over onto the next line.
    &   \makecell{2024 \\ Expected}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Use the `array` Package: it allows for more advanced column formatting.
Set the right Column to `m{2cm}`: it vertically centered the "2024" and "Expected" text.
Used `multirow` for Title: this aligned the title across two rows, centering it with "2024".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{@{}p{.8\textwidth} @{\extracolsep{\fill}}m{2cm}@{}}
  \multirow{2}{.8\textwidth}{\small{A very long paper title with author names and other bibliographic information that spills over onto the next line.}} & 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
    2024 \\ \small{Expected}
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This approach works for a single entry. However, if you use it twice in succession, with "Spring 2024" in the first one, and then "Fall 2024" in the second one, then the second column is not consistently right-aligned.